# Error on compiling the GAE instance ':api:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Everytime I try to run the GAE instance in AndroidStudio, I get this error:

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:api:assemble]
    Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 26 sec
    Information:1 error
    Information:0 warnings
    Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task     ':api:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
    > There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: 503 Service     Unavailable
      {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError",
        "message": "Backend Error"
       }
      ],
      "code": 503,
      "message": "Backend Error"
     }
    }
```

Anyone seen it before?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in my opinion, something is wrong with Cloud Endpoints in general. My working code from last week suddenly gives me these errors as well. It happened a few times before: [google code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9214)